# Upgrade to HTTPs if browser supports HTTPs

Tags: php, webserver

What is the best way to tell client browser to redirect to HTTPs page if and only if the browser support HTTPs protocol. That's mean that people still can access by using HTTP, but we enforce any user which browser that support HTTPs to use HTTPs.

### FAQ

> There is no clear motive to do such thing.

Currently, we force all of our user to use HTTPs. If they access to HTTP, they will redirect to HTTPs. The reason that we use HTTPs because it support "HTML5 Push Notification". This feature helps us retent our reader.

However, we also want to submit our website to Facebook Internet.org project which require us to functional without HTTP.

Comment: What set of visitors are you targeting who are using browsers that don't have support for HTTPS?

Comment: @Quentin, Currently, our website is HTTPs only. However, we are working on submitting our website to Internet.org project (a project that aim to provide a free internet to developing country). Their requirement is for us to support HTTP as well. That's why we want to enforce HTTPs to people that are using modern browser and HTTP for those who are using Internet.org project (probably rural area).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think this question is actually related to PHP, it seems more like a Server Fault question. But anyway:

**There is no clear motive to do such thing.**

The only reason why you should imply users won't be able to open HTTPS requests are either because your server isn't SSL/TSL certificated or the certificate is invalid/outdated.

But even so, your client should access the content anyway, given browser's alerts and restrictions, individual to each vendor settings. Both HTTP protocol modes, secure or not, are available **unless you set your server to deny** the non-secure one after the SSL/TSL implementation, as answered [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/429634/restrict-apache-to-only-allow-access-using-ssl-for-some-directories).

Unless we are talking about **extremely old browsers**, and by that I mean MS-DOS old, since [Netscape released the protocol in Feb/95](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#History_and_development).

Comment: First, this question could relating to PHP because there might be a HTTP header that we can send from server to client to enforce browser to upgrade itself to HTTPs protocol. Currently, we redirect every request to HTTP to HTTPs. There is motivation to do so. Internet.org is a Facebook's project to provide a free internet to developing country. Their requirement (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internet-org/platform-technical-guidelines) is that the website should work without HTTPs.

Comment: Well, then you just have to allow both HTTP and HTTPS protocols at your server's configs. This way, the client got to decide which one it will use.
Your website will force HTTPS if - and only if - your web server is configured to do so.
Read the answer I linked here to Server Fault's page, it's Apache-related, should help you! (unless you're using IIS, nginx or another web server which supports PHP)

Comment: Yes, except that the question is how to force user to use what their browser support. Support only HTTPs is easy to do. Support both HTTP and HTTPs is easy to do. Support both, but force them to upgrade if their browser HTTPs is not obvious to me yet. But I am almost found the answer now (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2817). Just need some testing.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think I didn't get your point, the approach seems mistaken to me. This RFC doc refers to the mandatory behavior of browser to request OPTIONS header when doing HTTP transfers by insecure means and the mandatory behavior of the server to respond it properly. When it talks about "upgrading", it means 101 "Switch Protocol" (3). In another way, it means the client can switch from HTTP to HTTPS whenever it wants (3.1), regarding if the server allows it or not (3.2).

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, if your server allows insecure HTTP request, you are attending Facebook's Internet.org requirement, as it is presented.